# File cached status without downloading - Dropbox Sync API

Tags: ios, dropbox

I would like to show the user a list of his dropboxed files and whether they are cached on the device or have to be downloaded first.

The way I tried to do this is to iterate the result of listFolder (Dropbox Sync API, iOS) and open the files to get the DBFileStatus. But by opening the files, they start to download.

Is there a way to get this information without downloading all the files?

Thanks Manuel